# Input text in iframe with puppeteer

Tags: javascript, iframe, puppeteer, redactor

I am using `"puppeteer": "^1.20.0",` for testing.

I have implemented the [wysiwyg editor redactor](https://imperavi.com/redactor/) as `iframe`:

```
<div class="redactor_box">
  <ul class="redactor_toolbar">
    <li class="redactor_btn_group redactor_btn_right">
      <ul>
        <li class="redactor_btn_container_switchmode">
          <a href="javascript:void(null);" title="Use BB Code Editor" class="redactor_btn_switchmode" unselectable="on" tabindex="-1"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="redactor_btn_group redactor_btn_right">
      <ul>
        <li class="redactor_btn_container_removeformat">
          <a href="javascript:void(null);" title="Remove Formatting" class="redactor_btn_removeformat" unselectable="on" tabindex="-1"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="redactor_btn_group">
      <ul>
        <li class="redactor_btn_container_bold">
          <a href="javascript:void(null);" title="Bold (Ctrl+B)" class="redactor_btn_bold" unselectable="on" tabindex="-1"></a>
        </li>
        <li class="redactor_btn_container_italic">
          <a href="javascript:void(null);" title="Italic (Ctrl+I)" class="redactor_btn_italic" unselectable="on" tabindex="-1"></a>
        </li>
        <li class="redactor_btn_container_underline">
          <a href="javascript:void(null);" title="Underline (Ctrl+U)" class="redactor_btn_underline" unselectable="on" tabindex="-1"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="redactor_btn_group">
      <ul>
        <li class="redactor_btn_container_fontcolor">
          <a href="javascript:void(null);" title="Text Color" class="redactor_btn_fontcolor" unselectable="on" tabindex="-1"></a>
        </li>
        <li class="redactor_btn_container_fontsize">
          <a href="javascript:void(null);" title="Font Size" class="redactor_btn_fontsize" unselectable="on" tabindex="-1"></a>
        </li>
        <li class="redactor_btn_container_fontfamily">
          <a href="javascript:void(null);" title="Font Family" class="redactor_btn_fontfamily" unselectable="on" tabindex="-1"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="redactor_btn_group">
      <ul>
        <li class="redactor_btn_container_createlink">
          <a href="javascript:void(null);" title="Link" class="redactor_btn_createlink" unselectable="on" tabindex="-1"></a>
        </li>
        <li class="redactor_btn_container_unlink">
          <a href="javascript:void(null);" title="Unlink" class="redactor_btn_unlink" unselectable="on" tabindex="-1"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="redactor_btn_group">
      <ul>
        <li class="redactor_btn_container_alignment">
          <a href="javascript:void(null);" title="Alignment" class="redactor_btn_alignment" unselectable="on" tabindex="-1"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="redactor_btn_group">
      <ul>
        <li class="redactor_btn_container_unorderedlist">
          <a href="javascript:void(null);" title="• Unordered List" class="redactor_btn_unorderedlist" unselectable="on" tabindex="-1"></a>
        </li>
        <li class="redactor_btn_container_orderedlist">
          <a href="javascript:void(null);" title="1. Ordered List" class="redactor_btn_orderedlist" unselectable="on" tabindex="-1"></a>
        </li>
        <li class="redactor_btn_container_outdent">
          <a href="javascript:void(null);" title="< Outdent" class="redactor_btn_outdent" unselectable="on" tabindex="-1"></a>
        </li>
        <li class="redactor_btn_container_indent">
          <a href="javascript:void(null);" title="> Indent" class="redactor_btn_indent" unselectable="on" tabindex="-1"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="redactor_btn_group">
      <ul>
        <li class="redactor_btn_container_smilies">
          <a href="javascript:void(null);" title="Smilies" class="redactor_btn_smilies" unselectable="on" tabindex="-1"></a>
        </li>
        <li class="redactor_btn_container_image">
          <a href="javascript:void(null);" title="Image" class="redactor_btn_image" unselectable="on" tabindex="-1"></a>
        </li>
        <li class="redactor_btn_container_media">
          <a href="javascript:void(null);" title="Media" class="redactor_btn_media" unselectable="on" tabindex="-1"></a>
        </li>
        <li class="redactor_btn_container_insert">
          <a href="javascript:void(null);" title="Insert..." class="redactor_btn_insert" unselectable="on" tabindex="-1"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="redactor_btn_group">
      <ul>
        <li class="redactor_btn_container_draft">
          <a href="javascript:void(null);" title="Drafts" class="redactor_btn_draft" unselectable="on" tabindex="-1"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="redactor_btn_group">
      <ul>
        <li class="redactor_btn_container_undo">
          <a href="javascript:void(null);" title="Undo (Ctrl+Z)" class="redactor_btn_undo" unselectable="on" tabindex="-1"></a>
        </li>
        <li class="redactor_btn_container_redo">
          <a href="javascript:void(null);" title="Redo (Ctrl+Y)" class="redactor_btn_redo" unselectable="on" tabindex="-1"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul><iframe style="width: 100%; height: 264px;" frameborder="0" class="redactor_textCtrl redactor_MessageEditor redactor_BbCodeWysiwygEditor redactor_NoAutoComplete"></iframe>
  <div class="redactor_editor_drop dragDisabled"><span>Uploads are not available.</span></div><textarea name="message_html" id="ctrl_message_html" class="textCtrl MessageEditor BbCodeWysiwygEditor NoAutoComplete" style="height: 260px; display: none;" data-css-url="css.php?style=3&amp;css=editor_contents&amp;d=1589815082"
    data-dialog-url="index.php?editor/dialog&amp;style=3" data-auto-save-url="conversations/save-draft" data-options="{&quot;autoSaveFrequency&quot;:&quot;60&quot;,&quot;bbCodes&quot;:[]}"></textarea></div>
```

I am trying to use:

```
        const editFrame = await page.frames().find(f => f.name() === 'redactor');
        const inputb = await editFrame.$('#html');
```

However, the iframe does not have any name. Furthermore, how do I then input into the iframe.

I highly appreciate your replies!

Comment: You can try [`frame.url()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#frameurl) instead of `frame.name()`, it shold be the same as `src` frame attribute.

Comment: @vsemozhetbyt Thx for your reply! What is my match for `f.url() === `? Appreciate your reply!

Comment: Oh, I see, sorry, the frame has no `src` attribute. By my tests, in this case `f.url()` is `'about:blank'`.